# Media API does'nt seem to work in Phonegap 3

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm an Android and Phonegap newbie. I want to create a simple MP3 player using the latest version of Phonegap. I've followed the tutorial to the letter and I've installed and tested the plugin for Phonegap. Half the time, the error fxn gets called by the Media fxn. The rest of the time, nothing at all happens. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" />
    <title>Player</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Audio player
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        playAudio("file:///android_asset/www/test.wav");
//            var path = window.location.pathname;
//            path = path.substr( path, path.length - 10 );
//            alert('file://' + path);
    }


        //
        var my_media = null;
        var mediaTimer = null;
        function playAudio(src) {
            if (my_media == null) {
                // Create Media object from src
                my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
            } // else play current audio
            // Play audio
            my_media.play();

            // Update my_media position every second
            if (mediaTimer == null) {
                mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                    // get my_media position
                    my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                    // success callback
                    function(position) {
                        if (position > -1) {
                            setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                        }
                    },
                    // error callback
                    function(e) {
                        console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                    }
                );
                }, 1000);
            }
        }

        // Pause audio
        //
        function pauseAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.pause();
            }
        }

        // Stop audio
        //
        function stopAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.stop();
            }
            clearInterval(mediaTimer);
            mediaTimer = null;
        }

        // onSuccess Callback
        //
        function onSuccess() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        }

        // onError Callback
        //
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

        // Set audio position
        //
        function setAudioPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="home" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Home</h1>                
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <p style="text-align:center;">MP3 Player:</p>
            <div data-role="controlgroup">
                <a onclick="playAudio('file:///android_asset/www/audio/tailtoddle.mp3');" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Play sound</a>                                      
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Made it work using the following steps:

- Deleted all files while keeping a copy of my index.html.
- Recreated the project and added Media + File plugins.